# Error with pinvoke function getKeyBoardLayout()

Tags: c#, pinvoke, keyboard-events, keyboard-layout, keylogger

I'm trying to write a basic background keylogger... Keyboard scanCodes and States are converted via pinvoke functions ToAsciiEx or ToUnicodeEx. These function have an argument for KeyboardLayout. I have a function (see below) for getting the current (active windows) keyboard layout. But this functions always returns 0. Error code is 6 (ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE).

Any sugessions ?

thx for answers

```
    static public IntPtr getActiveKeyBoardLayout() 
    {             
        int handle = 0;
        handle = GetForegroundWindow();

        IntPtr i = new IntPtr(handle);
        HandleRef hr = new HandleRef(wrapper, i);
        int pid;
        GetWindowThreadProcessId(hr, out pid);

        IntPtr layout = GetKeyboardLayout(pid);

        int er = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
        if (er > 0)
        {
            System.Console.Out.WriteLine("error " + er.ToString());
        }

        return layout;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing a process ID to the function.  It requires a thread ID.  The return value of GetWindowThreadProcessId().  The way you use Marshal.GetLastWin32Error() is wrong too, you should *only* use it when an API function returned a failure code.

Comment: thanks for your answer it's solved my problem. now the code is look more simplier:
`uint tid = GetWindowThreadProcessId(GetForegroundWindow(), IntPtr.Zero);
            IntPtr layout = GetKeyboardLayout(tid);
            return layout;`